# Texture baking in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I checked blender [Cycles todo](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/ToDo) and [Blender road map](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/Roadmap) but I can't find any word about this feature for cycles. Is there a plan for that in near future?

Comment: I don't think questions like these should be here, since the feature isn't present yet. You could and *should* try the mailing lists or IRC for queries pertaining to things like these..

Comment: I thought priciples of this page are  create as many answers as possible and answer stay there for ever.I don't want to bulling anyone to get that feature to blender I'm happy as it goes now.Developers doing awesome job.Every release has new features etc.I just wondered if baking on the schedule.

Comment: Utas, it is only my opinion, having some experience on sites like these. This is localized and unlikely to be of much assistance to anyone in the future as the feature hasn't even been fully planned yet and as both answers say below there isn't a set date either. Also the purpose of this site is to create a compilation of answers, not todo lists or feature requests etc.

Comment: ok I keep that on mind next time and I try to come up with smarter question.

Comment: @Utas Texture baking in Cycles is [on the way](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/02/08/try-baking-for-cycles-with-this-experimental-branch-now/) now.

Answer (score 6):

There's only few people who can handle Cycles code well, their time is spent mostly on keeping the system stable and well supported. New developers are being introduced now, but there's always need for more people here.

Another issue is priority & focus... Cycles main target is to be a "production rendering" environment. Rendering with baked lighting is not commonly regarded as a good workflow, for that development time can be better spent on advanced optimizing (caches etc). The main use case is for making light maps for game environments, which is very relevant but not on the first priority list for the current core devs.

Answer (score 2):

The feature currently isn't supported and there are no short term plans to add support, however this will likely be added at some point.